# Why does the jackknife reduce bias?

Tags: bias, bias-correction, jackknife

Given a sample $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, define $x_{(-i)}$ as the sample values excluding sample $x_i$. That is,
$$
x_{(-i)} = (x_1, \ldots, x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, \ldots x_n).
$$
Now given estimator $T(x)$ of parameter $\tau(\theta)$ based on the sample $x$, Lehmann and Casella (in the 2nd edition of Theory of Point Estimation) define the **jackknifed version** of $T(x)$ as
$$
T_J(x) = nT(x) - \frac{n -1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n T\left(x_{(-i)}\right).
$$
They claim that if $E[T(x)] = \tau(\theta) + O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, then $E[T_J(x)] = \tau(\theta) + O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$. Can someone explain why the jackknifed version of $T(x)$ has lower asymptotic bias then the original estimator?

Some notes:

- I've tried to work through this myself, but I think I'm unclear how to approach dealing with the expected values of the $T\left(x_{(-i)}\right)$ terms. In particular, it doesn't feel correct to treat them as independent from one another, and I don't really know how to approach the problem because of that.
- I posted [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4829597/why-does-the-jackknife-reduce-bias) on the mathematics stack exchange a few days ago, but didn't get any answers. After searching a bit, I've seen more similar questions on this forum, so I'm reposting here, with the hopes that the relevant experts are here :)

Comment: Welcome to CV! You'll indeed find similar questions here, the [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58759/how-to-derive-jackknife-bias-for-variance-and-mean) should be available as well.